# Spring, is there a way to get around not being able to extend 2 classes in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, polymorphism

I have an integration test with the following signature:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Example.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class CoolTest_IntegrationTest extends MyTestFrameworkAbstractClass {
```

`PrismIntegrationFramework` is an abstract class with a bunch of setup methods to make testing easier for people on my team.

Now, in Spring I heavily rely on `DynamicPropertySource` for injection dynamic Ip addresses, etc coming from my test containers.

Ideally, I want a separate "test harness" that I could inject/invoke based on the type of test. IE - I would have a GraphDBHarness that would be invoked when I write graph database integration tests.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = GraphClient.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class CoolTest_IntegrationTest extends MyTestFrameworkAbstractClass extends GraphDBHarness {
```

I know the above is invalid, but if this was *valid* then I would internally have something like :

```
public abstract class GremlinTestHarness {

  @DynamicPropertySource
  static void executeDynamicPropertyInjection(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add(
        GREMLIN_SERVER_KEY, () -> SupportedContainers.gremlinServer.getContainerIpAddress());
    registry.add(GREMLIN_SERVER_PORT, () -> SupportedContainers.gremlinServer.getFirstMappedPort());
  }
}
```

So in theory, if I had N of these, then I could inject the things I need or make the things I need available at will. Is this possible in Spring somehow?

Comment: Since you're already using Gremlin, is using Groovy (at least for testing) an option?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: There's no way around single inheritance of classes in Java. This was done purposely to avoid the [Diamond Problem](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/JavaAndDS/abstractInterface/05diamond.pdf).

**Long answer**: You can take advantage of multiple inheritance of interfaces. Also, just about every problem where you think you need inheritance, you can resolve with composition. In general, inheritance - although a necessary evil at times - violate encapsulation and is more problematic that you might think. Without knowing much about your specific implementation details, on the surface, your problem seems to fit the case where composition over inheritance is the way to go. I normally do a quick "is-a" check as the first step to see if inheritance makes sense. In your case:

`CoolTest_IntegrationTest` is-a `MyTestFrameworkAbstractClass` doesn't pass my logical test, because a test class is not a framework. A test class USES a framework. Even saying that a framework has-a test might not make much sense either. However, that is much better than tests inheriting from an abstract framework.  The `CoolTest_IntegrationTest` is-a `GraphDBHarness` doesn't pass my initial test either. A test also uses a DB harness, which implies composition.

Again, it seems you are trying to use inheritance for all the wrong reasons. Accessing fields/methods in a class is not in itself a good reason for inheritance. If you have an abstract framework class, you should only extend to make more specific types of frameworks, not to create test classes.

Use Dependency Injection to pass these items to your test class (i.e. DB harness) instead of using inheritance only  to gain access to its fields and methods.

That said, you could use single inheritance and create a inheritance chain where class A extends B and it extends C (instead of class A extending B and C). Again, in your case, I don't think this is the right approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ideally composition is what I want. I was hoping to understand if I can link into DynamicPropertySource annoation using a dependency injection approach. Any ideas if that's possible?

Comment: Example being: I use dependency injection (composition) to have a TestHarness on my class. The idea of it existing in my class allows auto invocation of the DyanmicPropertySource annotation to be picked up

Comment: I tried using @AutoWired but not sure how to properly do it

Comment: @John This tutorial should help you https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire

Comment: Basically, you add the properties to the class and "auto-wire" fully instantiated components to it. In your case the Test class should have the db harness and "framework" components as private data members of the class.

Comment: @John were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes. I created custom JUnit extensions to hijack some of the lifecycle callbacks in Spring. My question was more pointed toward the spring framework. I appreciate the response, but was ultimately looking for a solution to this use-case.

Comment: @John I don't know if you have sufficient privileges to do so, but you could post your solution to this problem. Click the button to add an answer and post your solution with the code you use to solve it. That could help others that might run into this same issue in the future.

Comment: Will do once I redact some package names. I appreciate your response, was informative and I upvoted it. Thanks!